# ,,Order by clause is not in select list" problem

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, distinct

I'm struggling with creating own auto-increment block. May you help me with reorganizing the example below? Works for TRUE in IF boolean expression, doesn't for FALSE ("#3065 - Expression #1 of order by clause is not in select list references column..."). I have found few solutions in the Web but I can't implement them in my case. I'd love to avoid changing anything "deeper" like sql_mode="" and others.
Example:

```
DECLARE temp_id INT;
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM operation_table WHERE client_id = 'some client') THEN
    SET temp_id := 1;
ELSE
    SET temp_id := (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM daily_operation ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) + 1;
END IF;
SET id := temp_id;
```

Comment: ```SET temp_id := (SELECT MAX(id) + 1 FROM daily_operation);``` is better IMHO. In any case the approach is not "thread safe": with multiple concurrent requests you will have the same temp_id.

Comment: Good point. So what is the common pattern in such cases?

Comment: Common pattern for what? You should use auto_increment, GUID or lock table. It is not clear from your question what you are trying to do so cannot suggest anything.

Comment: I am on writing a procedure auto-incrementing composite keys and this is why I am not using build-in option. In last comment I meant how to properly prevent multiple concurrent requests in this case but it leads to other topic. I'll search for it. Thanks.